# 5x2cv combined F test with hyperparameter tuning

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, cross-validation, model-evaluation, model-comparison

Does anything speak against using the [5x2cv combined F test](http://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/evaluate/combined_ftest_5x2cv/) combined with k-fold cross-validation in order to compare two learning algorithms? So, on each of the 10 training sets, we first apply k-fold cross-validation to obtain the most promising hyperparameter combination, then refit the selected algorithm and test the resulting model on the corresponding test set.

Everywhere I've looked I found this and similar tests only applied to a fixed hyperparameter configuration, this is why I'm a little irritated. Or is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: If we do this procedure for hyperparameter optimisation we run the risk of using a test without multiple comparison corrections. in that sense Demsar (2006) is more appropriate.

Comment: @usεr11852 Thanks a lot for the suggestion! Are you referring to the multiple testing problem? Because I only want to conduct one single test between l1-regularized logistic regression and gradient boosting trees. For both algorithms, I do not have fixed hyperparameters. So why exactly is it a bad idea to find these hyperparameters via k-fold cross-validations on each of the 10 training sets of 5x2cv combined F test?

Neither in Demsar's, nor in Dietterich's nor in Alpaydın's paper have I found anything about "hyperparameter tuning". Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: @usεr11852 After doing some further research, I have found the following passage in Salzberg "On comparing classifiers" (1997):

"Fortunately, one can perform virtually unlimited tuning without corrupting the validity
of the results. The solution is to use cross validation entirely within the training set itself. The recommended procedure is to reserve a portion of the training set as a “tuning” set, and to repeatedly test the algorithm and adjust its parameters on the tuning set. When the parameters appear to be at their optimal settings, accuracy can finally be measured on the test data."

Comment: I don't quite get, why we have to use a separate tuning set, because hyperparameter tuning can be achieved by k-fold cross-validation alone, but otherwise it seems as if my assumption that this procedure is fine seems right.